# Код работает не так, как я планировал(Python3, PyQt5)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Ниже оставлю код, в котором есть три класса - `ListWidget`, `Label` и `MyWindow`. `ListWidget` создает резиновую ленту, а `Label` создает виджет QLabel с закругленным изображением. **На эти классы не стоит обращать внимания, они точно правильно выполняют свои функции. Проблема(проблемы) в классе `MyWindow`.**

1. Тут я создаю кнопку `simple_btn`, которая потом попадает в
   вертикальный контейнер `box2`. Пока она не выполняет и не должна
   выполнять никаких функций.
2. Создаю `listWidget` - копию класса `ListWidget`, который наполняю виджетами QLable, полученными из класса `Label`.
3. Создаю `scrollArea`(QScrollArea), но пока нигде не размещаю.
4. Создаю QGridLayout - `box1`, куда первым виджетом(0, 0) добавляю
   `listWidget`.
5. К виджету `label1` привязываю метод класса `MyWindow` - `click()`,
   который с помощью `hide()` скрывает `listWidget` и создает
   привязанный к `scrollArea` контейнер QGridLayout - `box3`, если он
   еще не был создан. `box3` наполняется кнопками. В вертикальный
   контейнер `box2` попадает кнопка `back_btn`.
6. К кнопке `back_btn` привязваю метод `onButton`. Этот метод должен
   удалять все виджеты контейнера `box3`, скрывать `scrollArea` с
   помощью `hide()` и делать обратно видимым `listWidget` с помощью
   `show()`.

К сожалению, все это работает совсем не так, как я себе представлял:

1. Клик на `label1` действительно скрывает `listWidget`. **Но виджеты, которыми должен наполниться `box3`, не появляются в окне:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Если вернуться кнопкой `back_btn` к исходному состоянию окна и
   попробовать сделать еще один клик на `label1`, произойдет что-то
   странное. Как я понял, **`scrollArea` открывается в новом окне:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как мне починить код?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


class ListWidget(QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ListWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #self.setWindowTitle('ListWidget')
        #self.setStyleSheet('border-style: hidden;')
        self.resize(520, 400)

        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self.setEditTriggers(self.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAction)
        self.setSelectionMode(self.ContiguousSelection)

        self.setFlow(self.LeftToRight)
        self.setWrapping(True)
        self.setResizeMode(self.Adjust)

        self.setSpacing(10)

        self._rubberPos  = None
        self._rubberBand = None #QtWidgets.QRubberBand(QtWidgets.QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)

    def makeItem(self, lb):
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self)
        item.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(140, 140))
        self.setItemWidget(item, lb)


class Label(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, picture, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Label, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setMaximumSize(140, 140)
        self.setMinimumSize(140, 140)
        self.radius = 10 

        self.target = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())  
        self.target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)    

        p = QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(140, 140, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.target)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(self.target)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.simple_btn  = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')
        self.simple_btn.setFixedSize(100, 60)

        self.listWidget = ListWidget()

        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        self.content_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.content_widget)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self.label1 = Label('picture1.png')
        self.listWidget.makeItem(self.label1)
        self.label1.clicked.connect(self.click)
        self.label2 = Label('picture1.png')
        self.listWidget.makeItem(self.label2)
        self.label3 = Label('picture1.png')
        self.listWidget.makeItem(self.label3)

        self.box2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.box2.addWidget(self.simple_btn, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)

        self.box1 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)                                     
        self.box1.addWidget(self.listWidget, 0, 0)
        self.box1.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        self.box1.addLayout(self.box2, 0, 1) 

    def click(self):
        self.listWidget.hide()

        if not hasattr(self, 'box3'):
            self.box3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.content_widget)
        else:
            self.scrollArea.show()

        for n in range(1, 17):
            btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f'Button{n}')
            self.box3.addWidget(btn, n-1, 0)

        self.back_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Back', clicked=self.onButton) 
        self.back_btn.setFixedSize(100, 60)
        self.box2.addWidget(self.back_btn, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)

    def onButton(self):
        self.back_btn.deleteLater()
        col = 0
        for row in range(self.box3.rowCount()):
            w = self.box3.itemAtPosition(row, col).widget()
            w.deleteLater()
        self.scrollArea.hide()
        self.listWidget.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `self.scrollArea` появляется как окно, т.к. не была добавлена на форму. Хоть ее и создали, но у нее не было родителя, а виджет по умолчанию скрыт.. Т.е. ее нужно на какой-нибудь компоновщик добавить и скрыть в конструкторе `MyWindow` или в `def click(self):`

Comment: Я не знаю, как мог пропустить такое:) Спасибо большое, теперь все работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Любой виджет `Qt`, является окном, если у него нет [родителя](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#parentWidget).

Когда виджету указывается родитель (обычно это в конструкторе указывается или через метод [setParent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#setParent)), то содержимое виджета разместится на родителе.

Кст, если виджет располагается на компоновщике, то автоматически у него указывается родитель (поэтому у меня вызывает недоумение, когда вижу код с использованием компоновщиков и принудительной установкой родителя типа: `... = QLabel("...", self)`).

Поэтому, `self.scrollArea` появляется как окно, т.к. не была добавлена на форму. Хоть ее и создали, но у нее не было родителя, а виджет по умолчанию скрыт.. Т.е. ее нужно на какой-нибудь компоновщик добавить и скрыть в конструкторе `MyWindow` или добавлять на форму в `def click(self):`